# Bloom Filters Possible Problems when dealing with dynamic Sets

Tags: data-structures, computer-science, bloom-filter

im having a trouble understanding the possible problems of Bloom Filter with Dynamic Sets.

Can you tell me of some possible problems that may occur during adding/removing elements from the set?

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is bloom filters are not designed for removal.

For example. 
Assume

```
h1(x) = x %5
h2(x) = (x+2) % 5
```

And consider you have 2 elements in the set: `2,4`.

You have the bitset:

```
bitset = { 0, 1, 1, 0, 1 }
```

Now you want to remove 2 from the set. How do you do it? You have no idea that bitset[4] is common to both elements, and once you remove it, you will get the new bitset:

```
bitset' = { 0, 0, 1, 0, 0 }
```

But now, if you try to check if `4` is in it, you are going to get a wrong answer.

A possible solution to allowing removal to bloom filters is [counting bloom filters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bloom_filter#Counting_filters), but it has its negatives as well.

---

One more issue, is if your set is dynamic and can keep grow, it's not trivial to increase its size. You cannot simply allocate double the space, and rehash the entire collection, you have no idea what the original elements were.

Thus, bloom filter is used when its size is known (or bounded) apriori.